# Unexpectedly high memory usage in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a Python GAE app that stores data in each instance, and the memory usage is much higher than I’d expected. As an illustration, consider this test code which I’ve added to my app:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

bucket = []

class Memory(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        global bucket
        n = int(self.request.get('n'))
        size = 0
        for i in range(n):
            text = '%10d' % i
            bucket.append(text)
            size += len(text)
        self.response.out.write('Total number of characters = %d' % size)
```

A call to this handler with a value for query variable n will cause the instance to add n strings to its list, each 10 characters long.

If I call this with n=1 (to get everything loaded) and then check the instance memory usage on the production server, I see a figure of 29.4MB. If I then call it with n=100000 and check again, memory usage has jumped to 38.9MB. That is, my memory footprint has increased by 9.5MB to store only one million characters, nearly ten times what I’d expect. I believe that characters consume only one byte each, but even if that’s wrong there’s still a long way to go. Overhead of the list structure surely can’t explain it. I tried adding an explicit garbage collection call, but the figures didn’t change. What am I missing, and is there a way to reduce the footprint?

(Incidentally, I tried using a set instead of a list and found that after calling with n=100000 the memory usage increased by 13MB. That suggests that the set overhead for 100000 strings is 3.5MB more than that of lists, which is also much greater than expected.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that I'm *really* late to the party here, but this isn't surprising at all...

Consider a string of length 1:

```
s = '1'
```

That's pretty small, right?  Maybe somewhere on the order of 1 byte?  Nope.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof('1')
38
```

So there are approximately 37 bytes of overhead associated with each string that you create (all of those string methods need to be stored *somewhere*).

Additionally it's usually most efficient for your CPU to store items based on "word size" rather than byte size.  On lots of systems, a "word" is 4 bytes...).  I don't know for certain, but I wouldn't be surprised if python's memory allocator plays tricks there too to keep it running fairly quickly.

Also, don't forget that lists are represented as over-allocated arrays (to prevent huge performance problems each time you `.append`).  It is possible that, when you make a list of 100k elements, python actually allocates pointers for 110k or more.

Finally, regarding `set` -- That's probably fairly easily explained by the fact that `set` are even more over-allocated than `list` (they need to avoid all those hash collisions after all).  They end up having *large* jumps in memory usage as the set size grows in order to have enough free slots in the array to avoid hash collisions:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(set([1]))
232
>>> sys.getsizeof(set([1, 2]))
232
>>> sys.getsizeof(set([1, 2, 3]))
232
>>> sys.getsizeof(set([1, 2, 3, 4]))
232
>>> sys.getsizeof(set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
232
>>> sys.getsizeof(set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))  # resize!
744
```

Answer (score 0):

The overhead of the list structure doesn't explain what you're seeing directly, but [memory fragmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_%28computing%29) does. And strings have a non-zero overhead in terms of underlying memory, so counting string lengths is going to undercount significantly.

Comment: I agree that a character count might "significantly" undercount memory usage, but by a factor of ten?? Are you saying that the memory in my instance is 10% actual data and 90% garbage due to fragmentation? If true, the problem might not be fragmentation so much as grossly inefficient memory allocation algorithms within Google App Engine. malloc() was never this bad.

Comment: My experience with `malloc` differs. Look again at what that sample code is doing. It's causing periodic growth in the underlying memory region that backs the list, having at minimum to keep the old and new copy live while it copies data. And it's creating new strings in between. That's going to fragment that heap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but this is an interesting question.  It seems like it's more of a python memory management issue than a GAE issue.  Have you tried running it locally and comparing the memory usage on your local dev_appserver vs deployed on GAE?  That should indicate whether it's the GAE platform, or just python.

Secondly, the python code you used is simple, but not very efficient, a list comprehension instead of the for loop should be more efficient.  This should reduce the memory usage a bit:

```
''.join([`%10d` % i for i in range(n)])
```

Under the covers your growing string must be constantly reallocated.  Every time through the for loop, there's a discarded string left lying around.  I would have expected that triggering the garbage collector after your for loop should have cleaned up the extra strings though.

Try triggering the garbage collector before you check the memory usage.

```
import gc
gc.collect()
return len(gc.get_objects())
```

That should give you an idea if the garbage collector hasn't cleaned out some of the extra strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is largely a response to dragonx.

The sample code exists only to illustrate the problem, so I wasn't concerned with small efficiencies. I am instead concerned about why the application consumes around ten times as much memory as there is actual data. I can understand there being some memory overhead, but this much?

Nonetheless, I tried using a list comprehension (without the join, to match my original) and the memory usage increases slightly, from 9.5MB to 9.6MB. Perhaps that's within the margin of error. Or perhaps the large range() expression sucks it up; it's released, no doubt, but better to use xrange(), I think. With the join the instance variable is set to one very long string, and the memory footprint unsurprisingly drops to a sensible 1.1MB, but this isn't the same case at all. You get the same 1.1MB just setting the instance variable to one million characters without using a list comprehension.

I'm not sure I agree that with my loop "there's a discarded string left lying around." I believe that the string is added to the list (by reference, if that's proper to say) and that no strings are discarded.

I had already tried explicit garbage collection, as my original question states. No help there.

Here's a telling result. Changing the length of the strings from 10 to some other number causes a proportional change in memory usage, but there's a constant in there as well. My experiments show that for every string added to the list there's an 85 byte overhead, no matter what the string length. Is this the cost for strings or for putting the strings into a list? I lean toward the latter. Creating a list of 100,000 None’s consumes 4.5MB, or around 45 bytes per None. This isn't as bad as for strings, but it's still pretty bad. And as I mentioned before, it's worse for sets than it is for lists.

I wish I understood why the overhead (or fragmentation) was this bad, but the inescapable conclusion seems to be that large collections of small objects are extremely expensive. You're probably right that this is more of a Python issue than a GAE issue.

Comment: Hi, I apologize, I completely misread your code example, and didn't pay attention to the fact that bucket was a list, and was way off base.

Comment: If you're using the 2.7 runtime, you can use sys.getsizeof() to find out the size of your objects.

The higher than expected memory usage is because of python, and is not specific to GAE.  A python string is a string object, and not simply a string of characters.  Try doing dir("a") in the python shell to give you an idea of what's attached to a string object, then you'll figure the size is in line.